# In App Purchase subscriptions and using this status on an external platform

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

I have a mobile app that is paired with a react web app. The user purchases a subscription via the mobile app and this is stored in our database backend.

When the user logs into the react web app, it sees in the backend the user has a subscription and can deliver the correct content.

Now if the user cancels the subscription via their mobile store and logs into the web portal, there is no way for us to know the user has canceled. As far as I can tell the user has to log into the mobile app, we check at that point the status, see that it's expired or cancelled and then we can update our database accordingly.

How can I deal with this situation? Essentially a user can sign up, cancel the subscription and if they never log back into the mobile app they have free access to content via the web portal.

Comment: You know when the subscription expires. Store that date in your back end and deny service after that date. There is also a server integration from Apple that enables your server to receive subscription cancellation and renewal messages.

Comment: The server integration from apple for subscription cancellation is exactly what we need, do you have a link for more info as I'm finding it hard to find. Secondly, does the google play store have something similar?

Comment: This is the Apple documentation - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/ I don't know for sure about Play store since I don't do Android dev, but I think they do.